# Were there two types of monkeys who fought for Rama?

Tags: ramayana

> समुत्तिष्ठन्तु ते सर्वे हता ये युधि राक्षसैः |
> ऋक्षाश्च सह गोपुच्छैर्निकृत्ताननबाहवः || ६-१२०-१३

"Let all those monkeys and bears along with long-tailed monkeys, who have been killed in battle, by the demons and whose heads and arms have been severed, be alive and active again."

from

https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga120/yuddha_120_frame.htm

Answer (score 0):

Basis only this verse VI.120.13, it explicitly mentions `ऋक्षाश्च सह गोपुच्छै` which basically, literally means Bears (*ṛkṣas*) and Langūras (*gopucchās*).

So, just basis this verse what you conclude, depends upon what translation you adhere to. I'm reproducing below 5 different translations for the same verse. Kindly be the judge for yourself! - *To each his own.*

However, the Valmiki Ramayana does describe the manifestation of two different sub-specie of the divine-apes (viz. the *Vānaras* and the *Golāṅgūlas - literally mean 'cow-tailed'*), in the Bala Kanda itself. That I discuss at the end of this answer.

### 1. Gita Press Gorakahpur

> [Original Hindi Translation]:
>  जो युद्ध् में मारे गए हैं, और राक्षसों
> ने जिनके मस्तक तथा भुजाएँ काट डाली हैं, वे सब वानर​, भालु और लंगूर जी
> उठें । १३ ।
>
> English Translation of the above by Self:
>
> > 13. **Let all those *Vānaras*, Bears (*ṛkṣas*) and *Langūras* come back to life, who have been killed in the battle, with their heads and arms
> >     severed by the demons (*rākṣasas*).**

So, as per the [translation by Gita Press Gorakhpur Publications](https://archive.org/details/wg966/page/n1429/mode/2up), there are three types of beings to be revived, two of which, the *vānaras & [langūras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_langur)* maybe related, as in different sub-specie of a same specie.

---

### 2. Bibek Debroy

> [Chapter 6(108)](https://archive.org/details/valmikiramayance/page/n1259/mode/2up)
>
> Let all those apes regain their lives and stand up. Devoted to me and
> seeking to ensure my pleasure, they did not think about death. Through
> your favours, let them be united again. This is the boon I ask for.
> Let them be free of their pains. Let them be free of their wounds. Let
> them be full of strength and manliness. O one who grants honours! I
> desire to see **the golangulas and the Indras among the bears**. Wherever
> the apes are, let there be sparkling rivers and the best of roots and
> fruits, irrespective of the season.’ Hearing the words of the
> great-souled Raghava, the great Indra replied in words that bore signs
> of affection. “O son!” O descendant of the Raghu lineage! You have
> asked for a great boon. **The apes will arise**, as if they have awoken
> after being asleep. They will be filled with great delight and will
> meet their well-wishers, relatives, kin and near ones. O great archer!
> Even if the season isn’t right, the trees will be colourful with
> flowers and laden with fruit. The rivers will be full of water.’

Debroy doesn't seem to give any notion to 'two-different types of monkeys'.
At best, he uses apes *golangulas and the Indras among the bears*, besides the term apes.

So, as per this version. There seems to be only one type of the specie.

---

### 3. Dwarika Prasad Sharma

> [Original Hindi Translation]:
>   युद्ध में राक्षसों द्वारा जे
> वानर मारे गये हैं, वे जीवित हो उठ खड़े होंगे, लड़ाई में जिन रीछों
> (ॠक्ष) और वानरों को भुजाएँ काटी गयी हैं या मुँह फट गया है; वे सब पीड़ा
> और घावों से रहित तथा बल एवं पुरुषार्थ से सम्पन्न हो जायेगें ॥ १२ ॥
>
> English Translation of the above by Self:
>
> - 11,12. Let all those Vānaras and Bears (ṛkṣas)  come back to life, who have been killed in the battle, with their heads and arms severed,
>   let them become free from wounds, and re-vitalized with strength and
>   courage.

So, DP Sharma, in his [Hindi translation](https://archive.org/details/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SanskritTextWithHindiTranslation-DpSharma10/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SktHindi-DpSharmaVol08-YuddhaKandaUttarardh1927/page/n625/mode/2up), doesn't give mention *langūras*, unlike the Gita Press. So as per this translation, there is only one specie called *Vānaras*, who fought for Sri Rama.

---

### 4. M.N. Dutt

> [SECTION CXXII](https://archive.org/details/Valmiki_Ramayana_English_Prose_Translation_7_volumes_by_Manmatha_Nath_Dutt_1891_to_1894/Valmiki%20Ramayana%20-%20MN%20Dutt%20-%20Volume%206%20-%20Yuddha%20Kanda%201893/page/n423/mode/2up)
>
> O conferror of honour, I wish to see all these **monkeys, Golangulas
> and bears**, pale and hurt, unheart and gifted with strength and
> prowess like before. Let there be flowers, fruits and roots, even out
> of season wherever these monkeys shall live — and let rivers there be
> full of clear water.” Hearing those words of the high-souled Raghava
> Mahendra replied with words instinct with delight — “O my boy, O
> foremost of the Raghus, mighty is the boon thou hast prayed for — my
> words shall never be falsified, so let them be be fulfilled. ***(13).
> Let all those bears and Golangulas rise up who were slain in the
> conflict by Rakshasas and had their heads and arms severed.*** Let the
> monkeys gifted with their pristine strength and prowess rise up unhurt
> and healthy as if after the end of sleep. And being reconciled with
> their friends, relatives and kinsmen let them attain to excellent joy.

MN Dutt uses two words monkeys, *Golangulas* initially. and in the translation of the verse only *Golangulas*.

---

### 5. Hari Prasad Shastri

> [Chapter 123](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424751.html)
>
> May all those who have been slain in battle by the titans, the Bears
> and the *Gopucchas*, whose heads and arms have been severed, be
> resurrected!

HP shastri too uses only one name *Gopucchas* to describe the  Vānaras specie.

---

### Were there more than one subspecie of the Vānaras?

Yes. In the Bala-Kanda itself, this has been described, as to how on the order of god BrahmA different devas incarnated as *Vānaras*, *ṛkṣas* and *Golāṅgūlas* (गोलाङ्गूल) or *Gopucchās* (गोपुच्छा).

> [Valmiki Ramayana 1.17](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga17/bala_17_frame.htm)
>
> ते सृष्टा बहुसाहस्रा दशग्रीववधोद्यताः । अप्रमेयबला वीरा विक्रान्ताः
> कामरूपिणः ॥ १-१७-१७ ॥ ते गजाचलसंकाशा वपुष्मंतो महाबलाः ।
> **ऋक्षवानरगोपुच्छाः** क्षिप्रमेवाभिजज्ञिरे ॥ १-१७-१८ ॥
>
> > Thus the gods have procreated many thousands of such valorous and
> > guise changing monkeys who with their immeasurable strength and
> > bravery are manifest for the elimination of the decahedral demon
> > Ravana. **And they with their elephantine, mountainous and prodigious
> > bodies quickly took birth in bears, monkeys, sacred langoors.**
>
> English Translation by Sri Desiraju Hanumanta Rao

## To Conclude:

##### Since the above excerpts (from Valmiki Ramayana) clearly describes the incarnation of devas into bears, vānaras and the golāṅgūlas to fight against Ravana, it is therefore concluded that, yes, two types of Monkeys fought for Sri Rama.

---

As, an extra information, Brahmāṇḍa-Purāṇa III.7.175., gives an extended list of different types of Monkeys as follows:

> **हर्य्या स्तु हरयः पुत्रा गोलाङ्गूलास्तरक्षवः ॥ २,७.१७५ ॥ वानराः
> किन्नराश्चैव मायुः किंपुरुषास्तथा** । सिंहाव्याघ्राश्च नीलाश्चद्वीपिनः
> क्रोधिताधराः ॥ २,७.१७६ ॥ सर्पाश्चाजगरा ग्राहा मार्जारा मूषिकाः परे ।
> मण्डूका नकुलाश्चैव वल्कका वनगोचराः ॥ २,७.१७७ ॥
>
> > The following were the sons of Hari (i.e. Haribhadrā) viz. **various
> > varieties of monkey such as Haris, Golāṅgūlas, Vānaras**, Kinnaras,
> > Māyus and Kimpuruṣas, the hyaenes, the lions, the tigers, the dark
> > blue-coloured oxen, the Dvīpins, Pythons, crocodiles, cats, mice,
> > frogs, mongooses and Valkakas(?) found in forests.
>
> [English Translation](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362864.html#note-t-125904) by G.V. Tagare

---